# Docker java api , java - docker

Tags: java, docker, containers, devops, spotify-docker-client

Getting this error when I am running code, I am using java - docker version 3.0.14. I want to create  a container using java - docker and have to pass -config API with that and also I have to run a shell script in that newly created container

[image: error]

code snippet :

```
    CreateContainerResponse containerNew
     = client.createContainerCmd("owasp/zap2docker-weekly").withAttachStdout(true).withAttachStderr(true).withStdinOpen(true).withCmd("docker", "run", "--rm", "-i", "-p").exec();
```

Comment: You're passing "-p" to map ports but not supplying the ports to map.

Comment: I also tried that  case it was not working

Comment: What produces that image file?  You said you were getting an error; can you include it, as text, directly in the question?